# Add php code in between shortcode in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add php code inbetween shortcodes  in wordpress and I can get the following to work when the content in between is text.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[tab]
[tab_item title="ITEM_TITLE"]ADD_CONTENT_HERE[/tab_item]
[tab_item title="ITEM_TITLE"]ADD_CONTENT_HERE[/tab_item]
[tab_item title="ITEM_TITLE"]ADD_CONTENT_HERE[/tab_item]
[/tab]'); 
?>
```

I would like to add the following php code that generate the content in the tabs.

```
<?php 
 $args = array('post_type' => 'package','package-category'=>'South Africa',    'posts_per_page'=>6 );
 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>

<div class="four columns gdl-package-grid2">
 <div class="package-content-wrapper">
             <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible and how do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [String Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
echo do_shortcode('[tab]
[tab_item title="ITEM_TITLE"]' . $something . '[/tab_item]
[tab_item title="ITEM_TITLE"]' . $something . '[/tab_item]
[tab_item title="ITEM_TITLE"]' . $something . '[/tab_item]
[/tab]');
```

EDIT - This should work however you might have trouble with the [tab][/tab] shortcode around the loop. The easiest thing to do (if possible) would be to hard code whatever [tab][/tab] outputs around the loop. Hopefully this will help you out

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'package', 'package-category' => 'South Africa', 'posts_per_page' => 6);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail();

    $sc_content = <<<SCC
<div class="four columns gdl-package-grid2">
        <div class="package-content-wrapper">
            $thumbnail
        </div>
    </div>
SCC;
/**
 * The above line ("SCC;") MUST NOT have any other characters before it.
 * No spaces or tabs (indentation) can be before or after it,
 * those 4 characters must be the only characters on the line
 */

    echo do_shortcode('[tab_item title="ITEM_TITLE"]' . $sc_content . '[/tab_item]');



endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks..how would I covert the php code above to a string operator?

Comment: @user2798091 If you want all of the code inside of the shortcode and you want a separate shortcode for each post you can do something like this (see edited post). Hope it helps.

Comment: The edited answer doesn't work as the [/tab_item] [/tab] is generated as html

Comment: I will update the answer with another solution in about one hour as i am unable to do so right now. To sum it up - you could assign the entire gdl-package div to a variable and then use the string operators that i first mentioned to build the shortcode

Comment: JPiiONEFOURONE thanks for this but again it doesn't seem to work. Now only [/tab] is generated as Html. Could it be the way the tab shortcode is constructed?

Comment: I mentioned in the update that you may have to hard code whatever the [tab] outputs. Try this - instead of echo do_shortcode('[tab_item title="ITEM_TITLE"]' . $sc_content . '[/tab_item]'); try assigning it to a variable with .= and then echoing it out after the loop ends within the [tab] shortcode using string operators